# Using FontAwesome5 in Django

Tags: python, django, font-awesome, django-3.0

I am using [FontAwesome5](https://github.com/BenjjinF/django-fontawesome-5) in Django. But when I render the html using `icon.as_html` I only get the icon.

`<i class="fas fa-hands-helping " aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Is there a way to add `fa-stack-1x fa-inverse`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the template renderer:

```
{% fa5_icon 'hands-helping' class="fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" %}
```

I don't see any way to customize the IconField.

Even better, just use FontAwesome directly. You'll have more control.